# Fans going full speed after returning from suspend on Optimus laptop running Linux

Tags: linux, laptop, fan, suspend, optimus

I have* a problem with CPU fans on my Optimus laptop: after waking up from suspend fans starts going at full speed.

Reboot doesn't help, only full turn off and on.

It happens only with Nvidia GPU turned off**.

<sub>* used to have, but this problem liked to reappear once in a while</sub>

<sub>** if I recall correctly, could be the other way</sub>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using one of these kernel parameters:

- `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="pcie_port_pm=off"`
- `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi=! acpi_osi='Windows 2009' pcie_port_pm=off"`
- `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi!'Windows 2009"`
- `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi=! acpi_osi='Windows 2009'"`
- `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="Linux"`

If those won't help, then create `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/fan_madness_after_suspend.sh`:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

case "$1" in
    post)
        # Check device number with `lspci | grep -i nvidia` and replace it here!
        echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/power/control'
        ;;
esac
```

---

If you use Arch Linux with [optimus-manager](https://github.com/Askannz/optimus-manager) then this Bash script for switching GPU may be handy:

```sh
gpu-switch() {
    if [ ! -z $(command -v optimus-manager) ]; then
        if [[ "$(glxinfo | grep "OpenGL vendor")" =~ .*Intel.* ]] && \
                [[ "$(cat '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/power/control')" == "auto" ]]
        then
            read -p "Are you sure? System will reboot! [Y/n] " -r
            if [[ ! $REPLY =~ ^[Nn]$ ]]; then
                optimus-manager --set-startup nvidia_once
                reboot
            fi
        else
            optimus-manager --switch auto
            i3-msg exit
        fi
    fi
}
```